# Apex 19.2 doesn't display properly and it doesn't work in oracle 11g enterprise edition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

Apex 19.2. It doesn't work in Oracle 11g enterprise edition.

[image]

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Only apex doesn't work I have installed it very carefully and correctly but it is not opened in browser. I have already uploaded the screenshot of the problen above kindly click on ]1 in question description will show you the screenshot.

Comment: I saw the screenshot; it expects you to enter credentials. What happens when you do so? It looks like images are missing. Is that what bothers you?

Comment: I can not enter to the workspace. if I enter the workspace name, user name and password so after that when  I press the login button it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you create workspace at all (connected as ADMIN into INTERNAL workspace)? If not, no wonder it "doesn't work"; how would it?

Comment: I have tried to login to the internal workspace as admin but even the login button doesn't work when I press the login button nothing happens.  I don't know what should I do even I reinstalled the windows and also I I installed oracle 11g enterprise edition with apex 19.2 in another computer but I still I am encountering the same problem with apex.

Comment: Which version of 11g are you using? The documentation states that only 11.2.0.4 or higher is supported: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/htmig/Oracle-AE-installation-requirements.html#GUID-ED8FE111-A861-4A54-938B-CB3664D49C68

Comment: I am using 11.2.0.1.0 version. Hmmm that is the point my oracle version is lower then the supported version.

Comment: Thank you again from your usefull and consecutive responses.

Answer (score 0):

According to screenshot you posted, it looks as if *images* are missing. If that's so, try the following:

- go to SQL Workshop - RESTful services - ORDS based RESTful services - press **Register schema with ORDS** button
- enter schema alias (e.g. `arifullah_sa`, presuming `arifullah` is current schema)
- click **Save** button

That should do.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all update your ORDS by registering it with database
2. update your apex images as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).